# URLMappings With Optional Page Depth/URL Variable via Grails 3

Tags: grails, gradle, groovy

We're building a web application using Grails 3.0.11 that allows for custom page creation. Pages can optionally include tabs and users should be able to directly link to a specific tab using the URL structure `/page/tab`

So far no issue with `/page` but including the tab ID in the URL doesn't map to the assigned controller `public` (nor the action) and a 404 is thrown.

```
class UrlMappings {

    static excludes = ["/images/*","/assets/*","/layouts/*","/js/*", "/css/*"]

    static mappings = {
        /$page?/$tabid{
            controller= 'public'
            action='findPage'
            constraints{
                page(matches:/[a-zA-Z]+/)
            }
        }

        "/"(controller:'public',action:'findPage')

        "/admin/**"(controller:'admin')
        "500"(view:'/error')
        "404"(view:'/notFound')
    }
}
```

No other errors are being thrown by the compiler.

### Attempts:

`/$page/?$tabid` ==> /page/tabid is OKAY, /page is altered to 'pag' truncates and removed last char

`/$page?/?$tabid` ==> ditto...

`/$page/$tabid` ==> (expectedly) doesn't map to the controller for URL `/page` and correctly maps with URL `/page/tab`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Figured it out – the Grails specification is to include the question mark operator **at the end** of the variable name, when creating dynamic URLs.

```
 ... "/$page/$tabid?"{ ...
```

is the correct mapping.